# Console program in production deadlocked

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, deadlock

I have a program on my production server, that returned this error:

1. My main concern is if my program is on the production server why is
   it returning the location of my source code in the error?
2. Also what is the best way to debug this type of deadlock error and
   is it caused by a lack of resources on the server?

> Transaction (Process ID 73) was deadlocked on thread | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. :    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean
>   setTimeout)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Data.Extensions.Materializer`1.d__a.MoveNext()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Data.Extensions.Materializer`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at Console.Export.DataProvider.ExportData(IEnumerable`1
>   activitiesParam) in D:\Documents and
>   Settings\USER\Desktop\11_16_2011\ITS\Console\Export\DataProvider.cs:line
>   44
>
> at Console.Export.WarDataProvider.GetValues() in D:\Documents and
>   Settings\USER\Desktop\11_16_2011\ITS\Console\Export\DataProvider.cs:line
>   31
>
> at Console.Export.ExportEngine.Export(IDataProvider provider) in
>   D:\Documents and
>   Settings\USER\Desktop\11_16_2011\ITS\Console\Export\ExportEngine.cs:line
>   25

Comment: Is this program issuing multiple SQL commands in different threads or is it colliding with some other software while trying to use SQL DB?

Comment: Deadlocks don't really relate directly to lack of reaources. Simply : competing SPIDs each have locks that the other wants

Comment: @turowicx i dont believe it is running multiple threads, however it is running multiple updates sequentially, one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper examining of the deadlocks may be done with Sql Profiler, which has the some events for this

**but**

It shows not all the gathered useful info - saving the events as xml and digging inside of this xmls can give you much more info about the problem

**or**

You can use internal logging of deadlocks by sql server into its own errorlog. The behavior is controlled with the trace flags 1222 and 1204.

**and**

Often the proper indexing solving the deadlock problem if one of the involved in deadlock statements uses table or pk scan

Answer (score 1):

When you compiled your program did you compile it in debug rather than release configuration? If you do a debug build and deploy the files to the server, then it will display additional diagnostic information, which may be a good thing in this case.

- As to the best way to debug this I would recommend you do two things:
  Use [try, catch blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) to capture and handle the error in your
  program.
- Compare this program to the program it deadlocked with. You have a
  [deadly embrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433.aspx) that can sometimes be solved by changing the order in
  which tables are referenced within transactions.

Here is guidance on [handling Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177453.aspx).

Comment: ahh yes because it is telling me exactly which lines are failing. I was just a little worried it was actually trying to access my machine to run.